# Why does strtok segfault when given a *string but not when given a string[]?

Tags: c, strtok

Consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *str = "This is a test.";
    char *token;

    token = strtok(str," ");
}
```

It will segfault. But if I change *str to, say, str[80], it doesn't. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the difference between an array and a pointer?

Comment: Yes. Are you saying *str fails because it is a pointer, while str[] is an array? [This link](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html) says "Since arrays decay immediately into pointers, an array is never actually passed to a function.". This lead me to believe that, in both cases, I am passing a pointer to strtok.

Comment: Yes. However in the working case you are passing a pointer to *your array*, and in the non-working case you are passing a pointer to *a string literal*.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is that the type is wrong.

```
char *str = "This is a test.";
```

It may say `char*` but the thing on the right is actually `char const*` (C is very lax in allowing type punning (is that correct word)). Any attempt to modify a const is undefined behavior.

The function `strtok()` actually modifies the underlying string (by inserting '\0') so this is undefined behavior.

Fix by doing.

```
char str[] = "This is a test.";
```